# How do I use TODO progress tracking to track based on state instead of default

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm using org-mode to create a tracking system for completion of a game(Warframe). I created custom states based on the org mode guide on [5.2 Multi-state workflows](https://orgmode.org/guide/Multi_002dstate-workflows.html#Multi_002dstate-workflows) as follows.

```
#+TODO: TODO(t) | DONE(d)
#+TODO: NEED(n) BUILT(b) | MASTERED(m)
```

The current way it currently tracks is the default DONE/TOTAL. I'm looking for it to look like MASTED(BUILT)/TOTAL. The Custom tracking is not mentioned anywhere in the guide that I can find.
example of how it is tracked

```
*** Excalibur [0/2]
**** BUILT Regular
**** NEED Prime
```

example of how i would like it tracked

```
*** Excalibur [0(1)/2]
**** BUILT Regular
**** NEED Prime
```

---

Rephrased Question:

org mode has tracking cookies that only track Completed tasks vs total. Im looking to add a intermediate state that can also be tracked to show how many items are being worked on as well. I basicly want the tracking cookie to go from `DONE/TOTAL` to `DONE(INTERMEDIATE)/TOTAL` or in the case of above `MASTERED/TOTAL` to `MASTERED(BUILT)/TOTAL`

Kept original phrasing in hopes it would help explain what I'm looking for for an end result.

Comment: What do you meant by "the current way it works"? What is "it"?

Comment: So you are talking about statistics cookies? Although it's still unclear what you mean by `[0(1)/2]`: is it supposed to mean that if you use the `TODO|DONE` workflow, then 0 out of 2 items are complete, but if you use the `(NEED, BUILT)|MASTERED)` workflow, then 1 oout of 2 items is complete? If so, I don't understand why 1 item is complete: both of them are in non-MASTERED states, so neither of them is complete. Or maybe you mean something else. How are we supposed to figure it out if you don't provide complete explanations?

Comment: Much better, thanks! I'm not sure you can do what you want without making major changes to the code, but I have some additional questions: what should happen if you have two intermediate states? And why is `NEED` not an intermediate state? Imagine a `#+TODO: A B C D | E`, so some tasks may be in no state at all, some in A, some in B etc. The main problem I think  is how to deal with any such case in code that is generic and applicable to all such cases.

Comment: for multiple intermediate states would require different ways to display based on the use, my way is more of the how many would be complete if all was done or a way to show how many are being worked on. My specific example I think hints more how many are being worked on then working plus completed. Not every case of tracking intermediate states would need this. if this is not currently doable a better alternative probably a auto sort based on state, but how would a sort be logically defined so a desired order is obtained.